# Boolean value of Hibernate data class not updating in the Database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, dto

In the project I’m working on I have a hibernate data class which uses a DAO to save and update information. I need to set a value to the boolean property 'isPrimary' and save it in the my_class database.

Below is the data class,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_class")
public class MyClassData {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    // getter, setter
}

class Address {
    private String street;
    private boolean isPrimary;
    // getter, setter
}
```

when I try to update just the boolean value 'isPrimary' as shown below and try to update the database it is not updated.

```
MyClassData myClassData = myclassDAO.getById(id);
myClassData.getAddress().setIsPrimary(false);
myclassDAO.update(myClassData); // doesn’t update in the db
```

However if I try to update boolean value along with another string property both properties are updated in the database

```
MyClassData myClassData = myclassDAO.getById(id);
myClassData.setName(“John”)
myClassData.getAddress().setIsPrimary(false);
myclassDAO.update(myClassData); // updates both values in the db
```

Is there a specific reason why this is happening and how can I update just the boolean value in the database?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a project ready to test your code but I am pretty sure that you need to specify to Hibernate that the class `Address` is embedded in your entity by adding `@Embeddable` at the top of the class Address, like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_class")
public class MyClassData {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    // getter, setter
}

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private boolean isPrimary;
    // getter, setter
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the @Embeddable and Embedded annotations for the entity class as you suggested. It still isn't working. Could this be because the class Address is a jsonb column and not another table?

Comment: Embedded object properties are persisted in columns of the same table of the entity. The only other reasons that can think of is : 1) the Address class must be in antoher file (if not already, I cannot say with your post) 2) the name of the property "isPrimary" do not respect the Java naming convention (it should be primary, with isPrimare()/setPrimate(boolean) as getter and setter.